# esp32_cam read and process image

Tags: c++, arduino, tensorflow-lite, esp32

I am trying to use tensorflow-lite on a esp32_cam to classify images.
I defined the following sub-tasks that i need to solve:

1. Take photo
2. Reduce size of photo to (e.g.) 28x28 pixels grayscale
3. run inference with trained model

For now I am stuck between point 1 and 2 and cannot get it solved.
What i have done so far:
I save an image into buffer using `esp_camera_fb_get()`. Afterwards I put the values from the buffer inside a 2D array.
However, when I print out some of these values, they never become 0 nor 255, even though I coverd the whole lens or put a bright light source close to it.

I have four questions:

1. How do i correctly record an image?
2. How can I convert it into a 2D array?
3. How can I downsample the size from (e.g.) 160x120 to 28x28?
4. how can I correctly `Serial.print()` each pixel value to copy the values and plot them on my computer (e.g. with python matplotlib)

`#define  CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER`

```
 #include <esp_camera.h>
 #include "camera_pins.h"

 #define FRAME_SIZE FRAMESIZE_QQVGA
 #define WIDTH 160
 #define HEIGHT 120    

 uint16_t img_array [HEIGHT][WIDTH] = { 0 };


 bool setup_camera(framesize_t);
 void frame_to_array(camera_fb_t * frame);
 void print_image_shape(camera_fb_t * frame);
 bool capture_image();

 void setup() {
     Serial.begin(115200);
     Serial.println(setup_camera(FRAME_SIZE) ? "OK" : "ERR INIT");
 }

 void loop() {
     if (!capture_image()) {
         Serial.println("Failed capture");
         delay(2000);

         return;
     }

     //print_features();
     delay(3000);
 }



 bool setup_camera(framesize_t frameSize) {
     camera_config_t config;

     config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
     config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
     config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
     config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
     config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
     config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_GRAYSCALE;
     config.frame_size = frameSize;
     config.jpeg_quality = 12;
     config.fb_count = 1;

     bool ok = esp_camera_init(&config) == ESP_OK;

     sensor_t *sensor = esp_camera_sensor_get();
     sensor->set_framesize(sensor, frameSize);

     return ok;
 }



 bool capture_image() {

     camera_fb_t * frame = NULL;
     frame = esp_camera_fb_get();

     print_image_shape(frame);

     frame_to_array(frame);

     esp_camera_fb_return(frame);

     if (!frame)
         return false;

     return true;
 }


 void print_image_shape(camera_fb_t * frame){

     // print shape of image and total length (=heigth*width)
     Serial.print("Width: ");
     Serial.print(frame->width);
     Serial.print("\tHeigth: ");
     Serial.print(frame->height);
     Serial.print("\tLength: ");
     Serial.println(frame->len);
 }

 void frame_to_array(camera_fb_t * frame){

     int len = frame->len;
     char imgBuffer[frame->len];
     int counter = 0;

     uint16_t img_array [HEIGHT][WIDTH] = { 0 };

     int h_counter = 0;
     int w_counter = 0;

     // write values from buffer into 2D Array
     for (int h=0; h < HEIGHT; h++){
         //Serial.println(h);
         for (int w=0; w < WIDTH; w++){
             //Serial.println(w);
             int position = h*(len/HEIGHT)+w;

             //Serial.println(position);
             img_array[h][w] = {frame->buf[position]};

             //Serial.print(img_array[h][w]);
             //Serial.print(",");
             //delay(2);
         }
     }


     //Serial.println("Current frame:");

     Serial.println("=====================");

 }
```

camera_pin.h:

```
#if defined(CAMERA_MODEL_WROVER_KIT)
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    21
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM      35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM      34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM      39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM      36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM      19
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM      18
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       5
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM       4
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM    23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    22

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_ESP_EYE)
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM   -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM    4
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM    18
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM    23

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM      36
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM      37
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM      38
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM      39
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM      35
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM      14
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM      13
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM      34
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM   5
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM    27
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM    25

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_PSRAM)
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     25
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    22
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_M5STACK_WIDE)
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     -1
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    15
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM     27
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     22
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     23

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM        5
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM       32
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     26
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     21

#elif defined(CAMERA_MODEL_AI_THINKER)
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

#else
#error "Camera model not selected"
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't worked with the ESP32 Camera so I can't talk about that but I've done a similar project on STM32 so here is all I can answer:

#### 1. How do I correctly record an image?

I also had trouble setting up a camera on my microcontroller so I thought the same as you, getting back the image to the PC through serial. Please refer to point 4.

#### 2. How can I convert it into a 2D array?

I suspect you want to do this for copying it to the tflite micro model input buffer. If that's the case, you don't need to! You can write your flattened 1D image array to the model input buffer because that's what tflite micro actually expects:

```c
uint8_t img_array[HEIGHT * WIDTH] = { 0 }; // grayscale goes from 0 to 255. fits in 8bits
TfLiteTensor* model_input = nullptr;
...
void setup(){
    ... // Create your tflite interpreter and rest of your code
    model_input = interpreter->input(0); // get model input pointer
}
void loop() {
    ...
    // tflite model has input shape [batch_size, height, width, channels]
    // which in turn is [1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1] one channel because I think you are
    // using grayscale images, otherwise 3(RGB)
    // but tflite micro expects flattened 1D array so you can just do this
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT*WIDTH; i++){
        // Assuming your model input expects signed 8bit integers
        model_input->data.int8[i] = (int8_t) (img_array[i] - 128);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: The last line takes the `model_input` pointer to the model input structure and accesses its `data` member(see [this](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-structures-pointers) if you are not familiar with struct pointers in C). Then, since I assumed your model input data type is 8 bit signed integers, it accesses the data [union](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) with `int8`. If your model input data type were 32-bit floats you could have used `model_input->data.f[i]` for example. [Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cb42c4dea198ce27de5f0e7098ab2973af48672c/tensorflow/lite/c/common.h#L342) is the source code with all available access types. After correctly addressing the model input buffer, we assign the corresponding `img_array` pixel data. Since the pixel data ranges from [0, 255], we need to convert it to a valid signed 8-bit integer type and range, so you must subtract 128, resulting in a [-128, 127] range.

Hopefully, you get the idea. Let me know if you are using other formats like RGB565 and I'll give you a different snippet.

**EDIT**: If you are capturing RGB images, the most used format is RGB565, meaning there is a pixel data every 16 bits(5 for red, 6 for green, 5 for blue). Here is a snippet that transforms an image captured in that format to RGB888(which is what your model will probably expect) and copies it to the model input buffer:

```c
// NOTICE FRAME BUFFER IS NOW uint16_t to store each pixel
uint16_t img_array[HEIGHT * WIDTH] = { 0 }; 
TfLiteTensor* model_input = nullptr;
...
void setup(){
    ... // Create your tflite interpreter and rest of your code
    model_input = interpreter->input(0); // get model input pointer
}
void loop() {
    ...
    // Fill input buffer
    uint32_t input_ix = 0; // index for the model input

    // tflite model has input shape [batch_size, height, width, channels]
    // which in turn is [1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 3] three channels because RGB
    // but tflite micro expects flattened 1D array so you can just do this
    for (uint32_t pix = 0; i < HEIGHT*WIDTH; pix++){
       // Convert from RGB55 to RGB888 and int8 range
       uint16_t color = img_array[pix];
       int16_t r = ((color & 0xF800) >> 11)*255/0x1F - 128;
       int16_t g = ((color & 0x07E0) >> 5)*255/0x3F - 128;
       int16_t b = ((color & 0x001F) >> 0)*255/0x1F - 128;

       model_input->data.int8[input_ix] =   (int8_t) r;
       model_input->data.int8[input_ix+1] = (int8_t) g;
       model_input->data.int8[input_ix+2] = (int8_t) b;

       input_ix += 3;
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.barth-dev.de/online/rgb565-color-picker/) is a step by step guide on RGB888 to RGB565 in C, I just did the inverse of that. You may have noticed the multiplications after masking out the color channel bits. Take red for example: once you mask out the bits `(color & 0xF800) >> 11)` the red value will go from [0, (2^5)-1] but we want a [0, 255] range, so we divide by that number( (2^5)-1 = 31 = 0x1F ) and multiply by 255, giving the range we wanted. We can then subtract 128 to get a [-128, 127] signed 8-bit range. The fact that multiplication is done before is to keep precision. The blue channel is the same and in the green one, we divide by (2^6)-1=63=0x3F because it has 6 bits.

#### 3. How can I downsample the size from (e.g.) 160x120 to 28x28?

You could implement an algorithm in C but I took the easy way: I added a preprocessing lambda layer in my already trained model that did just that:

```py
IMG_SIZE = (28, 28)

def lm_uc_preprocess(inputs):
    # 'nearest' is the ONLY method supported by tflite micro as of October 2020 as you can see in
    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a1e5d73663152b0d7f0d9661e5d602b442acddba/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.cc#L70
    res_imgs = tf.image.resize(inputs, IMG_SIZE, method='nearest') 
    # Normalize to the range [-1,1] # (OPTIONAL)
    norm_imgs = res_imgs*(1/127.5) -1 # multiply by reciprocal of 127.5 as DIV is not supported by tflite micro
    return norm_imgs
```

**EDIT**: Most computer vision models expect the image input value range to be [0, 1] or [-1, 1] but pixel values are usually 8-bit, so their range is [0, 255]. To *normalize* their values to a desired range [a, b], we can apply the following formula:
[image: normalization_formula]

In our case,  min(x)=0, max(x)=255, a=-1, b=1. Therefore, each normalized value is x_normalized = x_value/127.5 -1.
Intuitively you can see how 255/127.5 -1 = 1, and how 0/255 -1 = -1. That is where the 127.5 and -1 values come from.

Now you can define your complete model:

```py
capture_height, capture_width, channels = (160, 120, 1)

uc_final_model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer((capture_height, capture_width, channels), dtype=tf.float32),
    keras.layers.Lambda(lm_uc_preprocess), # (160, 120) to (28, 28)
    my_trained_model
])

# You should quantize your model parameters and inputs to int8 when compressing to tflite after this
```

This way, the final model had an input shape equal to the camera capture resolution. This allowed me to copy the image array as shown in point 2.

#### 4. How can I correctly Serial.print() each pixel value to copy the values and plot them on my computer (e.g. with python matplotlib)

I tried a couple of things and this is what worked for me: You can try printing the values like this `123, 32, 1, 78, 90,`(i.e. separated by commas) which should be fairly easy to do. Then, if you are using Arduino you can use [this cool program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iz_AETY9o5E&feature=emb_title&ab_channel=TabletopRobotics) to log the serial data. If you are not using arduino, Putty has logging features. Then you can do something like this:

```py
with open("img_test.txt") as f:
    str_img_test = f.read()

img_test = np.array(str_img_test.split(",")[:-1], dtype=np.uint8)
img_test = img_test.reshape(160, 120)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(img_test)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The process of capturing an image and saving the log is a bit cumbersome but it shouldn't be too frustrating as this is only to debug if your image was captured correctly.

This is a very general question so let me know if I missed something or you want more depth on some aspects.

### Edit

I've made public(and open source) my full code and documentation [on this repository](https://github.com/PHANzgz/embedded-deep-learning) which contains a very similar app to what you are building. Furthermore, I'm also planning on porting the computer vision example to ESP32. Please note the repository is under development and will be for a while, although this example is already finished(pending revision).

I think a lot of people interested in deep learning on microcontrollers will find the repository interesting and useful.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! This clarified many of my questions. I seems to work more or less now, but I will get more into it the next days. Where does 127.5 in section 3. lm_uc_preprocess(inputs) come from? And could you explain the last line of the loop function in section 2, please?
Also a code snipped for RGB images would be great!

Comment: Sure, you are capturing images in RGB565 mode right? That's why you have a uint16_t img_array yes?

Comment: For now i use grayscale, but i would like to expand to rgb once I got the basic model running. Grayscale should have uint8_t, whereas rgb affords uint16_t if i got this right

Comment: You are correct. I have added everything you've asked for. Let me know if there is still anything unclear. You may be wondering why not add the RGB565->RGB888 inside the preprocessing model as well. I've tried and it turns out dtype uint16 is not supported and neither are the bitwise operations in tflite micro. I'm planning on releasing my full code and documentation of my similar app soon so you can get some more inspiration. I'll add a link at the end of the answer this week.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great answer!! I would appreciate to have a look at your code, which would surely help me develop and improve mine!

Comment: No problem! I have just made the code public, check the edit at the end of the answer. I really hope you find it useful and inspiring. The app you are interested in is "person-car-detection" in the repository.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code!
I tried to resize the image with the code you have provided. When running it i receive:
'Register_RESIZE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR' is not a member of 'tflite::ops::micro'
I use platformIO library TensorFlowLite_ESP32@^0.9.0. The tensorflow source on github includes the Register_RESIZE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, but i cannot make it make it work. Any ideas how to solve this or a workaround like resizing in c++? I tried looking up some code for it, but my knowledge of c++ is quite restricted.